# "Missing required paramter" with all Social Auth providers

Tags: 8, authentication-authorization

The problem: I've just installed `social_auth_google`, `social_auth_twitter` and `social_auth_linkedin` modules. All the modules are configured (`Client ID`, `Client Secret`, and other similar fileds). The modules are installed through `composer require ...`, so I assume that all dependencies are there, but to confirm here's the list of the enabled modules:

`Social              Social API (social_api)         Enabled   8.x-2.0-beta4
  Social              Social Auth (social_auth)       Enabled   8.x-2.0-beta4
  Social              Social Auth Google              Enabled   8.x-2.0-beta3
                      (social_auth_google)
  Social              Social Auth LinkedIn            Enabled   8.x-2.0-beta1
                      (social_auth_linkedin)
  Social              Social Auth Twitter             Enabled   8.x-2.0-alpha2
                      (social_auth_twitter)`

Besides these, composer also installed some non-Drupal packages to `vendor` directory:

- `league/oauth2-client (2.3.0)`
- `league/oauth2-google (2.2.0)`
- `abraham/twitteroauth (0.9.2)`
- `league/oauth2-linkedin (2.1.0)`

I've embedded "Social Auth Login" block to "Content" region of `/user/login` and `/user/register` pages, and I've got a decent-looking login/register pages as the result.

But the problem is that neither of the embedded authentication providers doesn't work. If I click g+, I get *"Error: invalid_request. Missing required parameter: client_id"*. When I click twitter, I get: *"You could not be authenticated, please contact the administrator."*. With LinkedIn I get: *"You need to pass the 'client_id' parameter"*.

Obviously I'm missing something... Any help?

Comment: Please don't include links to your site. As it simply will become invalid once the issue got fixed. Apart from that it can be easily considered as spam aiming to gain some traffic and/or SEO juice.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that you are missing an API key or something very similar. Please simply read the docs thoroughly, for example https://github.com/drupalsocialinitiative/social_auth_google/blob/8.x-2.x/README.txt

Comment: @leymannx - Thanks for the suggestion about link to my site. I've planned to remove it once it's fixed. And it definitely isn't about traffic/SEO - as you can see the site isn't available at all (access denied).

Comment: Regarding API keys - I've set them all appropriately, for all the providers (g+, Twitter, LinkedIn). I've rechecked that. But for some reason it looks that social_auth simply doesn't send these. I hope that someone else have experience with the same issue... Thanks for trying to help!

Comment: Hm I see, I see, thing is, debugging always needs to be done by you. The chance someone else had the problem as well is very low and would instead make this question better posted on drupal.org. Only you know the specific setup of your site and your server etc., that's why this issue is difficult to solve from afar, requiring lots of back and forth questioning in comments, which simply is too broad for a fact-based Q&A. As soon as you know the root cause of the issue and don't know how to solve it, feel free to come back and ask a new question. Good luck :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, let me offer an alternative answer which will allow you to keep outgoing proxy in place.

After reviewing the code of both `social_auth_google` and `social_auth_linkedin`, I've concluded that they are both suffering from the same bug. And in both cases the bug is fixed in `2.x-dev` version. But dev version doesn't work because of some other issue (a missing class issue), so I couldn't migrate to dev. Instead I've kept their latest beta versions, and fixed the bug manually. I'll explain the fix on `social_auth_google` module, but the same thing should be done with `social_auth_linkedin` also.

The bug is in `social_auth_google/src/Plugin/Network/GoogleAuth.php` file, in `initSdk()` method. Here's the snippet with the bug:

`if ($this->validateConfig($settings)) {
    // All these settings are mandatory.
    $league_settings = [
      'clientId' => $settings->getClientId(),
      'clientSecret' => $settings->getClientSecret(),
      'redirectUri' => $this->requestContext->getCompleteBaseUrl() . '/user/login/google/callback',
      'accessType' => 'offline',
      'verify' => FALSE,
      'hostedDomain' => $settings->getRestrictedDomain(),
    ];`

```
// Proxy configuration data for outward proxy.
$proxyUrl = $this->siteSettings->get('http_client_config')['proxy']['http'];
if ($proxyUrl) {
    $league_settings = [
        'proxy' => $proxyUrl, 
    ];
}

return new Google($league_settings);
```

}

What's happening there is that, if an outgoing proxy is defined, instead of adding `'proxy'` value to `$league_settings` variable, it overrides it completely. For this reason we don't have `'clientId'` defined anymore, thus getting the error from the original question: "Missing required parameter: client_id".

So what we need to do is to simply change

`if ($proxyUrl) {
        $league_settings = [
            'proxy' => $proxyUrl, 
        ];
    }`

with

`if ($proxyUrl) {
        $league_settings['proxy'] = $proxyUrl;
    }`

After this change, and the same exact change in `social_auth_linkedin` module, both authentication providers will work.

Comment: Nice findings! You should definitely share them on drupal.org!

Comment: @leymannx: Thanks! Regarding sharing on drupal.org - social_auth guyz are already aware of the bug (it's fixed in 2.x-dev version). Thanks for taking care of Drupalers here! :)

Answer (score 1):

I've found the reason for the problem: outgoing proxy. The web server where I have my website installed doesn't have direct internet access, but it uses an outgoing proxy.

Regarding `social_auth_twitter` - it was my mistake - outgoing proxy was blocking access to `api.twitter.com`. After configuring the proxy to allow this traffic - Twitter authentication started working as expected.

But regarding the other two (`social_auth_google` and `social_auth_linkedin`) - no requests ever reached the proxy, meaning that these modules *don't know* how to use the proxy.

I've ensured that the proxy is configured correctly:

- Environment variables `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, `no_proxy`, `HTTP_PROXY`, `HTTPS_PROXY`, `NO_PROXY` are configured as needed;
- In `VirtualHost` element (Apache configuration) I'm ensuring that these environment variables are available by setting the appropriate `PassEnv` lines (`mod_env` module);
- `settings.php` file contains the appropriate `$settings['http_client_config']['proxy']['http']` (and other) configuration.

At the end of the day - everything else (installing and updating modules, etc.) is working normally through the proxy, so proxy configuration isn't the problem.

It looks that, at least for now, you cannot have `social_auth_google` and `social_auth_linkedin` if your web server is behind a proxy. Another very disappointing fact is that **there are no any logs** in `/admin/reports/dblog`, so you cannot know that modules are struggling to access their corresponding API endpoints. Hopefully it'll be resolved in future versions. For now **you simply have to allow direct access**, and remove outgoing proxy completely.